# How to transform items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I change the items in this list? I want to change

`[A1 (76113),A2 (7614),...,A11 (73887)]`

to

`[A01, A02,..., A11]`

Thanks

Comment: `transformed_list = [transform_item(item) for item in original_list]`

Comment: What is the (76113) supposed to mean, do we have to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a simple, one, all it looks like you're doing is  remove the number, and make "A1" to A01". It assumes that each item is a string, if that is wrong please tell me.

```
def transItem(item):
    parts = item.split()
    aLet = parts[0][0]
    aNum = parts[0][1:]
    if len(aNum) <=1:
        aNum = "0"*(2-len(aNum)) + aNum
    return aLet+aNum
oldList = ["A1 (76113)","A2 (7614)","A11 (73887)"]
newList = [transItem(itm) for itm in oldList]
```